# How to specify total number of character in C# number formatting?

Tags: c#, string, formatting, numbers

Is there a way to specify total number of characters when formatting doubles?

Lets say I have 0.00012345678, and I specify total number of characters (7), I want to get 1.23e-4. Format "G7" would give 1.2345e-4.

More examples:

```
0.00000012345678F -> 1.23e-7 
0.00012345678F    -> 1.23e-4 
0.12345678F       -> 1.23e-1 
1.2345678F        -> 1.23457 
12.345678F        -> 12.3457
12345678F         -> 1.234e8
```

Answer (score 2):

You probably want to use the "e" format string like so...

```
String.Format("{0:0.00e+0}", number);
```

Comment: Thanks, it works with my example, but that's not exactly what I want :) Let me try to give more details: my goal is to be able to specify total number of characters in the output, so if I specify 4 I want to get these results:

0.00000012345678F -> 1.23e-7
0.00012345678F -> 1.23e-4
0.12345678F -> 1.23e-1
1.2345678F -> 1.2345
12.345678F -> 12.345

Answer (score 1):

You have a misunderstanding about the meaning of "precision". For a floating point number, "precision" means the number of **significant digits**, so the result returned by "G6" is correct.

If you want a fixed number of characters, use a [custom format string](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0c899ak8.aspx) like Jason suggested.

Answer (score 0):

{0:00e+0}

http://blog.stevex.net/string-formatting-in-csharp/